# Scalar fields with definite weight under conformal maps as sections of some bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, fiber-bundles, conformal-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold. A scalar field in $(M,g)$ is merely a map $\phi:M\to \mathbb{R}$. Under a diffeomorphism $f:(M,g)\to (M,g)$ it transforms to $\phi' = \phi\circ f$. We then have the coordinate expression: $$\phi'(x')=\phi(x).\tag{1}$$

We can also say that $\phi$ is a section of the trivial bundle $M\times \mathbb{R}$ which sends $p\mapsto (p,\phi(p))$.

Now let $f:(M,g)\to (M,g)$ a conformal map with scale factor $\Omega$. This means we have $f^\ast g=\Omega^2g$. A scalar field of weight $\Delta$ transforms, in coordinates, as $$\phi'(x')=\Omega^{-\Delta}(x)\phi(x)\tag{2}.$$

My question here is: what is the underlying geometrical structure that gives rise to this transformation law? Is there some bundle in which $\phi$ is a section so that the conformal factor naturally appears when transforming the section in an appropriate way?

To compare: the transformation law of a scalar naturally follows from $\phi' = f^\ast \phi$ expressed in coordinates. More generally for tensor fields of arbitrary rank, the usual transformation law under general coordinate transformations follows from the geometric transformation using the pullback $f^\ast$ and pushforward maps $f_\ast$. I wanted to know if we have something like that for transformation under conformal maps.

What comes to mind is a possible construction of some "bundle of conformal frames", a principal ${\rm Conf}(M,g)$-bundle over $M$, such that $\phi$ is a section of some associated bundle by the appropriate representation of ${\rm Conf}(M,g)$. In particular, the dimension $\Delta$ is encoded in the representation in which $\phi$ transforms. I just don't know how to make this precise yet.

Comment: Do you have any precise reference? I am a bit confused by your question

Comment: Sure, there standard reference is the book Conformal Field Theory by Di Francesco. In chapter 4 if I'm not mistaken he discusses the transformation law (2). Another reference is the lecture notes by Hugh Osborn (https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ho/CFTNotes.pdf) where he discusses these transformation laws in section 2.2. In either case they are only considering conformal maps $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ between flat space and itself. I'm interested in a geometrical formulation with more general manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

Your $\phi$ is a section of the conformal density bundle of weight $-\Delta$.  Curry and Gover wrote a [nice introduction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7559.pdf#page15) to conformal geometry which explains this well (the hyperlink goes to the page where density bundles are defined).

Comment: Thank you @JeffreyCase, that's amazing. I have skimmed through it and it seems exactly like the formalization of the concept of quasi-primary fields in CFT that I was looking for. I'm going to study it in detail.